# How to disable all custom styles in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I override default styles of some controls in code.  After this i want to disable all custom styles for all  children(deep recursion) of some control. For example xaml:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style  TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Button>red style here is ok</Button>
        <TextBlock> also ok</TextBlock>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <!-- magic command to disable ALL custom styles, for all controls like 
                <Style TargetType = "FrameworkElement"/>   -->
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Button> no style plz </Button>
            <TextBlock> bad style-_- </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

I know that i can use style=null, but its bad solution for me, because i need to apply this trick for every type of controls.  How can i solve my problem?

Comment: You want style for small group of controls and no style for a larger group right? If that's the case you can used named resources for you styles

Comment: I want to style big group of controls, and  no style for big group of controls, so named styles is not solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could inject a blank Style that would take precedence over your other Style. Like:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style  TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button>red style here is ok</Button>
    <TextBlock> also ok</TextBlock>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <!-- magic command to disable ALL custom styles, for all controls -->
            <Style  TargetType="Button" />
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" />
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Button> no style plz </Button>
        <TextBlock> bad style-_- </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: For that solution i need to know which styles are overrided, and to reset each style, thats also bad.